# curb not working with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curb

I have a simple class that is using curb to retrieve data. Everything works just find from the command line, but when I load it into my rails application WebBrick crashes on the "require 'curb'" statement.

I'm extremely new to ruby so I'm not sure how exactly to debug the error from webbrick to determine what is wrong.

If someone knows how to solve this issue that would be great, if someone could also point me into the right direction to start troubleshooting the issue myself that would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Rails can't find the gem. If it works from the command line, the gem should be installed correctly and working, so that's not your problem.

Check your `environment.rb` file. If you don't see a dependency for `curb`, add it:

`config.gem 'curb'`

Then check dependencies from the terminal:

`rake gems`

You should see `curb` listed as 'Installed'. If not, try reinstalling:

`rake gems:install`

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, I was able to install passenger and everything works just fine.